# UITableViewCell background color with alpha different behavior

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uicolor, ios7

I set the same color `([UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.8])` for `TableHeader` and for each Row (for in Row in `layoutSubviews`). It works great in `iOS 6` and `iOS 5` but in `iOS 7` i'm getting different behavior.

This color works for header in the same way but for cell alpha became as 1. I've set it to 0.6 and appearance was like alpha 0.8 for `iOS 6 or 5`.

**So problem is:** by setting the same alpha for `TableHeader` (or other view) and for `TableViewCell` we will get different appearance, but I need the same and I don't want to hack.

And one more, with `[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0];`

It becomes fully transparent, so i think that there is no views below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the best solution:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 68.0/255.0 green: 125.0/255.0 blue: 190.0/255.0 alpha: 0.8];
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a UITableViewCell background color with an alpha less than 1 for ios 6 & 7, do this:

```
UIColor *myBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed: 68.0/255.0 green: 125.0/255.0 blue: 190.0/255.0 alpha: 0.8];
if([UITextView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(textContainerInset)]) //is ios7 or above
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=myBlue;
} else
{
     cell.backgroundColor=myBlue;
}
```